# unusual large number of fs.file-max

Tags: 20.04

I have a machine running ubuntu desktop 20.04 and looking at the fs parameters could not believe the file-max value: 9223372036854775807 which is the largest 64 bit signed integer.

I never touched this parameter and cannot say how i ended with this value.

The only fs parameter I have in sysctl.conf is:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
```

The machine which is hosting several services for my personal use is working fine since years now.

The question I have is this a valid value, or an error in reporting? should I change it to some reasonable value like ... 2000000 or should I leave it like that?

Why this high number for file.max :

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/a8b627aaed409a15260c25988970c795bf963812

Comment: it is the same on my 20.04.3 test server. I did not know the command to look, so for other readers: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Comment: Why do you think it's unusual?      2⁶³−1

Comment: Why does this bother you? Why would you want to limit max file size?